# Openshift Nightmare - lost all mysql innoDB data unexpectedly

Tags: php, mysql, database, innodb

My website is hosted over openshift, everything was working fine by then end of the day, I turned off my PC and slept, in the morning I saw I was not able to login to website or see any events.

Then I opened phpMyAdmin to see what is going on, when I clicked my database it says,
--No tables found.

Though, tables names were displayed under database name, I was not able to access either data or structure of the table, I was Screwed!!!

I opened the log files, but couldn't understand it.

Then I googled, how can I get my data back using ibdata1 and iblog flies, but the procedure was tricky. I had a feeling that I lost my data, that was also confirmed after digging a bit.

I want to know why this happened, so it shouldn't happen in future. I couldn't figure out the reason yet.

Here is my log file:-

```
151218 00:09:24 mysqld_safe Logging to '/var/lib/openshift/56182a0f0c1e6645c6000/mysql//stdout.err'.
151218 00:09:24 mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /var/lib/openshift/56182a0f0c1e6645c6000/mysql/data/
151218 00:09:24 mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /var/lib/openshift/56182a0f0c1e6645c6000/mysql/data/
151218  0:09:24 [Note] /opt/rh/mysql55/root/usr/libexec/mysqld (mysqld 5.5.45) starting as process 439115 ...
151218  0:09:24 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
151218  0:09:24 InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
151218  0:09:24 InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
151218  0:09:24 InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
151218  0:09:24 InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
151218  0:09:24 InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 32.0M
151218  0:09:24 InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
151218  0:09:24 InnoDB: highest supported file format is Barracuda.
151218  0:09:24  InnoDB: Waiting for the background threads to start
151218  0:09:25 InnoDB: 5.5.45 started; log sequence number 1595675
151218  0:09:25 [Note] Server hostname (bind-address): '127.4.242.2'; port: 3306
151218  0:09:25 [Note]   - '127.4.242.2' resolves to '127.4.242.2';
151218  0:09:25 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '127.4.242.2'.
151218  0:09:25 [Warning] 'proxies_priv' entry '@ root@ex-std-node687.prod.rhcloud.com' ignored in --skip-name-resolve mode.
151218  0:09:25 [Note] Event Scheduler: Loaded 0 events
151218  0:09:25 [Note] /opt/rh/mysql55/root/usr/libexec/mysqld: ready for connections.
Version: '5.5.45'  socket: '/var/lib/openshift/56182a0f0c1e6645c6000/mysql//socket/mysql.sock'  port: 3306  MySQL Community Server (GPL)
151218  0:09:53 [ERROR] Cannot find or open table ecell/e_users from
the internal data dictionary of InnoDB though the .frm file for the
table exists. Maybe you have deleted and recreated InnoDB data
files but have forgotten to delete the corresponding .frm files
of InnoDB tables, or you have moved .frm files to another database?
or, the table contains indexes that this version of the engine
doesn't support.
See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-troubleshooting.html
how you can resolve the problem.
151218  0:09:53 [ERROR] Cannot find or open table ecell/events from
the internal data dictionary of InnoDB though the .frm file for the
table exists. Maybe you have deleted and recreated InnoDB data
files but have forgotten to delete the corresponding .frm files
of InnoDB tables, or you have moved .frm files to another database?
or, the table contains indexes that this version of the engine
doesn't support.
See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-troubleshooting.html
how you can resolve the problem.
151218  0:09:53 [ERROR] Cannot find or open table ecell/pastevents from
the internal data dictionary of InnoDB  the .frm file for the
table exists. Maybe you have deleted and recreated InnoDB data
files but have forgotten to delete the corresponding .frm files
of InnoDB tables, or you have moved .frm files to another database?
or, the table contains indexes that this version of the engine
doesn't support.
```

Comment: Note, MySQL was restarted today. The fact MySQL can't find tables in the InnoDB dictionary hints that ibdata1 was recently created, after the start. Probably it was deleted a while ago. Probably it was lost before MySQL restarted (why did it restart?). Anyway, if you still have ibd files, you can restore the tables, if innodb_file_per_table was OFF (all tables are in ibdata1) then to restore you need ssh access to the box and root privileges. You should tell more about your environment

Comment: Hi Naman. Probably your ib_logfiles and ibdata files are messed up. You will need to recover the db. ask me if you need to help.